# How to type a setState in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to type a setState in my application. How would I type in this context?
The message to type is:

> (property) setPageNumber: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction>
> The type '{ movies: MovieData[]; pageNumber: number; setPageNumber:
> React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction>; }' cannot be assigned to
> type 'MoviesContextData'.   The object literal can only specify known
> properties and 'setPageNumber' does not exist in type
> 'MoviesContextData'.

types:

```
  export type MoviesContextData = {
    movies: MovieData[];
    pageNumber: number;
}

export type MovieData = {
    id: number;
    backdrop_path: string;
    poster_path: string;
    title: string;
    release_date: string;
    vote_average: number;
}
```

```
 import {
    useContext,
    createContext,
    useEffect,
    useState
} from "react"

import { MoviesProviderProps } from "../interfaces/props"
import { MovieData, MoviesContextData } from "../interfaces/types"

import axios from "axios"
import { POPULAR_BASE_URL } from "../services/api"

const MoviesContext = createContext<MoviesContextData>(
    {} as MoviesContextData
)

export const MoviesProvider = ({ children }: MoviesProviderProps) => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MovieData[]>([])
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`${POPULAR_BASE_URL}&page=${pageNumber}`)
            .then(response => {
                setMovies(response.data.results)
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <MoviesContext.Provider value={{ movies, pageNumber, setPageNumber }}>
            {children}
        </MoviesContext.Provider>
    )

}

export const useMovies = () => {
    const context = useContext(MoviesContext)

    return context
}
```

Comment: You are passing `setPageNumber` as a value to the context even though you haven't added that to the context's type

Comment: it's telling you that the `MoviesContextData` type deosn't have a `setPageNumber` prop. So you would have to add that there if it's part of the context as it seems that you want it to be

Comment: Yes, I understand that I need to add the type of setPageNumber. I need to know how I would do the typing. If I do "setPageNumber:() => void". Does not work.

Answer (score 0):

it's telling you that the **MoviesContextData** type doesn't have a **setPageNumber** prop. So when you do `<MoviesContext.Provider value={{ movies, pageNumber, setPageNumber }}>` TS complains, cos you are trying to assign a prop that doesn't exist in the Context type.

So you would have to add that to the type, if it's part of the context as it seems that you want it to be.

Even more if people are going to use that set function from the context

```
export type MoviesContextData = {
    movies: MovieData[];
    pageNumber: number;
    setPageNumber: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>
}
```

Comment: I tried to do as you said, but this message appeared: "Generic type 'SetStateAction' requires 1 type argument(s)."

Comment: @Stlick sorry for that. Just updated the example. Just add the number type as generic value